# limits of sequences of functions and uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

I have a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined by

$$
 f_n(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   0,
 &  x=0,\\
   x,      & 0< x<1/n,
\\
   x^2,       & 1/n <x.
  \end{cases}
$$
I need to determine the limit for the function and to determine if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The limit is $x^2$, and because $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<1/n$ it is the uniform convergence.

Comment: why is the limit $x^2$? Can you explain please??

Comment: @Togepi Because $f_n(x)=x^2$ for every $x>\frac1n$.

Comment: Why is $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \frac1n$?       Thank you thou..

Comment: @Togepi Because for $x\geq1/n$ it is equal to 0, and $0<x^2<x<1/n$ for $x<1/n$. (Somewhere there should be the weak inequality, but it is not determined in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $n \geq 2$

$$\sup_{x}|f_n(x)-x^2| = \left|\frac1{n}-\frac1{n^2}\right| \rightarrow 0$$

and the sequence converges uniformly to $f(x) = x^2$.